# Ubuntu 18.04 (GUI) cannot create a directory - nothing comes up on right click

Tags: gui

I just made the step from "4flags" to Ubuntu on my desktop. Managed to install OS ( Ubuntu 18.04), have my WiFi running, installed Flash on Firefox (CLI ), I can NOT create ANY directory via GUI in any of my HOME directories. I could create a file ( to PDF ) that sits alone in my **Documents** directory, but when clicking my right mouse (in Documents dir) to create a new one... nothing happens.

It doesn't matter if I click right or left button, once or twice, there is no response. I do NOT get the options to create anything. I have the OS only the second day, not going to do it through CLI yet, there must be some simple reason for it, like having (NOT) the rights on my PC to write or create folders. Where can I check this? What could it be? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are using Nautilus *file manager*, change from list-view to icon-view (top right on mine, icon has four squares) and you  should have some white space visible (in your home folder, existing folders & files visible).  Right clicking on the 'blank' space should provide a menu with "New Folder, New Document..."  Select 'New Folder'

Comment: If you want a more user friendly GUI, I recommend you install cinnamon or mate instead of Gnome, to get the latest cinnamon open "Software & Updates", add under "Other Software" http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu and in the terminal write "sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop" - then logout and in the login screen click the cogwheel, choose cinnamon and login

Comment: thanks for both of yours fast responses, I would rather stick to Ubuntu for now. guiverc --- yes, it is Nautilus file manager ( new one / grey with only one drawer :) I did just that , no response either . I am always clicking the right button to get ( like in Win -- shouldn´t be named here :) to the menu..Absolutely no difference between right / left clik / double / simple. non ..no POPup menu comes.

Comment: Seems that you have no right-click in nautilus, right? Did you try the right-click with another app like firefox for exemple. ... 

Did you try the 'context menu key' wich do the same as right click in Windows. It does the same in Ubuntu ... 

(You can create a new folder in nautilus with [Crtl+Shift+N])

Comment: cmak.fr , correct..., the right click ( fysicaly/mechanicaly works ) but there is no response to it in Firefox either. I can get the Firefox from the bar to the screen with both, left or right click, but there is no Pop-Up menu comming from it. I have probably problem with a folder permission. I just tried to create it through  [Crtl+Shift+N], and it worked. I created new folder with a chosen name. But the right click will not give me any options. Nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: Actually, if I didn´t have folder permission, I could NOT create the folder with [Crtl+Shift+N] either. But I did manage to do this. It is just the right click and the menu options that I do not get.

Comment: solved ! I found it . Ubuntu 18.04 Right Click NOT working:

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/

Comment: thanks for all your help.., will stay with LINUX 4ever now... :)

Comment: this reminds me of when I installed 17.10 and my right click stopped working (same as the change in 18.04). For days I thought it was a bug in Firefox and a separate one in Telegram because I didn't realise that I was using right click to access various options - I just assumed the options were suddenly unavailable.